# SQL Import Data - Insert Only if it doesn't exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL server management tool 2008 to import data to the web host database. I have tables with primary keys. (Id for each row) Now I can import data normally. But when I am importing data for the second time..I need to make sure only those rows that doesn't currently exists only then it's inserted. If there's a to do this using the wizard? If not, then what's the best practice?

Comment: I would load it into a staging table and do an `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ... ` or `MERGE`

Comment: @KDB . . . Learn about the `MERGE` statement.  It does this and much more.

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert the data into a temp table
2. use left join with main table to identify which records to insert

--

```
CREATE TABLE T1(col1 int)
go

CREATE TABLE Temp(col1 int )
go

INSERT INTO T1
SELECT 1 
UNION 
SELECT 2

INSERT INTO TEMP
SELECT 1 
UNION 
SELECT 2
UNION 
SELECT 3 
UNION 
SELECT 4 

INSERT INTO T1 
SELECT TEMP.col1
FROM Temp 
LEFT JOIN T1 
  ON TEMP.col1 = T1.col1
WHERE T1.col1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this some time ago, maybe it can help:

```
insert into timestudio.dbo.seccoes (Seccao,Descricao,IdRegiao,IdEmpresa)
  select distinct CCT_COD_CENTRO_CUSTO, CCT_DESIGNACAO, '9', '10' from rhxxi.dbo.RH_CCTT0 
  where CCT_COD_CENTRO_CUSTO not in (select Seccao from TimeStudio.dbo.Seccoes where idempresa = '10')
```

Or, just use simple a IF Statement.

Comment: My experience is that not exists is faster and more reliable than not in.

Comment: Almost always `not exists` is better than other options, [the man has tested it](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).